Sheafification with values in general categories through fiber products?
Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{C}$ a category. Denote by $\operatorname{Top}(X)$ the category of open subsets of $X$, with inclusions as morphisms.
A $\mathcal{C}$-valued presheaf on $X$ is a functor $\mathcal{F} \colon \operatorname{Top}(X)^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathcal{C}$.
If we assume that $\mathcal{C}$ has all products, we can say that such an $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf if for every open set $U \subseteq X$ and every open cover $\mathcal{U} = \{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ of $U$ the following diagram is an equalizer:
$$\mathcal{F}(U) \to \prod_{\alpha \in A} \mathcal{F}(U_\alpha) \rightrightarrows \prod_{\alpha,\beta \in A} \mathcal{F}(U_\alpha \cap U_\beta).$$
Given a $\mathcal{C}$-valued presheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, we can ask whether it has a sheafification: this is a $\mathcal{C}$-valued sheaf $\mathcal{F}^\#$ on $X$ together with a morphism of presheaves $\varphi \colon \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}^\#$ satisfying the universal property that, for every $\mathcal{C}$-valued sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ on $X$ and morphism of presheaves $\psi \colon \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$, there exists a unique morphism of (pre)sheaves $\psi^\# \colon \mathcal{F}^\# \to \mathcal{G}$ through which $\psi$ factors (i.e. $\psi^\# \circ \varphi = \psi$).
When $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of sets (or some other nice concrete category), it's relatively easy to construct the sheafification, using compatible families of germs (i.e. the sheaf of sections of the étalé space). However, the traditional way to formulate this construction uses in an essential way the fact that objects in $\mathcal{C}$ have elements.
Nevertheless, this Stacks project lemma shows that this construction of sheafification for presheaves of sets can be phrased categorically as a fiber product. This suggests a way to try to generalize this construction to more general target categories.
More precisely, if $\mathcal{C}$ is a category with products and directed colimits (so that we can define stalks) and $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\mathcal{C}$-valued presheaf on $X$, we can associate to it a $\mathcal{C}$-valued sheaf $\Pi\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ given by $$(\Pi\mathcal{F})(U) = \prod_{p \in U} \mathcal{F}_p,$$ together with the obvious morphism of presheaves $\mathcal{F} \to \Pi\mathcal{F}$.
If we assume moreover that $\mathcal{C}$ has all fiber products, we can define the sheafification $\mathcal{F}^\#$ of $\mathcal{F}$ as the fiber product
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD} \mathcal{F}^\#(U) @> >> (\Pi\mathcal{F})(U)\\ @VV V @VV V\\ \prod_{p \in U} \mathcal{F}_p @>>> \prod_{p \in U}(\Pi\mathcal{F})_p \end{CD},$$
where the bottom horizontal map collects the maps induced between stalks by $\mathcal{F} \to \Pi\mathcal{F}$, and the right vertical map collects the stalk projections of the sheaf $\Pi\mathcal{F}$ coming from the open set $U$.
I was able to check that this construction does indeed define a sheaf $\mathcal{F}^\#$, and there is a natural morphism $\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}^\#$, but I got stuck in trying to show that this satisfies the universal property of sheafification. To do this, we need to define a morphism of sheaves $\mathcal{F}^\# \to \mathcal{G}$ going in the opposite direction of the universal property of the fiber product.
When $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of sets, we could consider an element $s \in \mathcal{F}^\#(U)$, consider a cover of $U$ by open subsets where $s$ comes from a section of $\mathcal{F}$, and glue the corresponding sections of $\mathcal{G}$. However, I have no idea how to do something similar for a more general $\mathcal{C}$.
One thing that would suffice to do is to show that, if $\mathcal{G}$ is a sheaf, then the sheafification morphism $\mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{G}^\#$ is an isomorphism, but this seems to run into exactly the same problems.

Question: Does this construction using fiber products satisfy the universal property of sheafification, for such a general $\mathcal{C}$? If yes, how can one prove this? And if not, are there any reasonable extra conditions on the category $\mathcal{C}$ so that this would be true?

Note: I know that there are alternative constructions of sheafification that could work in this setting (e.g. the plus construction, that when applied twice to a presheaf always gives a sheaf, and even works over more general sites). However, in this question I am interested in this particular construction, as it is closer to the more familiar construction in the category of sets.
Edit: Some words on the fiber product construction, in response to a comment of Martin Brandenburg. The reason why the fiber product works as a compatibility condition seems a bit subtle to me indeed. It has to do with the fact that the bottom and right maps are not the same, even though they go between the same objects.
Thinking in the category of sets: a section of $\Pi\mathcal{F}$ over $U$ is a choice $(s_p \in \mathcal{F}_p)_{p \in U}$ of a germ of $\mathcal{F}$ at every point of $U$ (with no compatibility condition); a germ of $\Pi\mathcal{F}$ at $p$ is doing this in some small neighbourhood of $p$.
This means that an element in the product $\prod_{p \in U} (\Pi\mathcal{F})_p$ is choosing, simultaneously at every $p \in U$, a collection of germs of $\mathcal{F}$ at points in a small neighbourhood $U_p$ of $p$; these neighbourhoods will overlap in general, which means that altogether we're possibly picking multiple different germs at each point. This is something like $([U_p,(s_{p,q} \in \mathcal{F}_q)_{q \in U_p}])_{p \in U}$.
The right vertical map sends $(s_p \in \mathcal{F}_p)_{p \in U} \mapsto ([U,(s_q)_{q \in U}])_{p \in U}$, i.e. it sets all the $U_p = U$ and always uses the same germs at every "copy" of each point.
On the other hand, the bottom horizontal map looks at the collection $(s_p \in \mathcal{F}_p)_{p \in U}$ and chooses for each $p \in U$ a neighbourhood $U_p$ and a section $S_p \in \mathcal{F}(U_p)$ representing the germ $s_p$. Then it maps $$(s_p \in \mathcal{F}_p)_{p \in U} \mapsto ([U_p,((S_p)_q \in \mathcal{F}_q)_{q \in U_p}])_{p \in U},$$ i.e. each of the "local" collections of germs for each $p$ comes from a section $S_p \in \mathcal{F}(U_p)$. However, we might be choosing different germs for different "copies" of a given point.
Requiring that the two maps agree corresponds to requiring that our initial family of germs is compatible, in the sense that it is locally given by the germs of some section.

I would be very surprised if the construction works just when products, fiber products and filtered colimits exist. See this open question of mine, and I still believe that the associated sheaf does not exist for $\mathbf{Top}$ as the target. Also notice that the assumptions for the plus-construction are much more delicate in the book by Kashiwara-Schapira. We also need to say somehow how colimits interact with limits. After all, you are in particular using a product of colimits here.

Isn't this the so-called sheaf of discontinuous sections? You have not done anything to ensure that "nearby" points are mapped to germs that are compatible.

@ZhenLin That's what the fiber product does (for some reason I also don't fully understand right now). See the stacks project.

I find it implausible as a general lemma. Probably the correct version will be based on the Godement resolution and the fact that the inverse image functor of a surjective geometric morphism is comonadic.

@MartinBrandenburg I edited the question with some comments on how the fiber product gives a compatibility condition, as I also found it not immediately obvious, and it might be helpful to people reading it. Thank you for the pointer to Kashiwara-Schapira, I'll take a look there. I should say I would be okay in requiring existence of more limits/colimits or some compatibility condition between limits and colimits, if it makes this construction go through.

Requiring two maps agree should be expressed as an equaliser, not a pullback. In this case it makes no difference because both maps are monic. Thus this is the Godement resolution in disguise...

@ZhenLin I agree that formulating this as an equaliser is more intuitive than as a pullback, and that they compute the same object in categories like Set. Are you claiming that they compute the same object in general (due to the maps being monic)? I don't know how to see this.

They do. Reduce to the case of $\textbf{Set}$ by the Yoneda embedding.

First, let me state my scepticism regarding this generalisation/definition of "sheaf".
It is possible to eliminate the hypothesis on the existence of products by using more complicated diagrams, or by using the Yoneda embedding.
But then this definition applied to, say, the category of local rings does not reproduce the accepted definition of "sheaf of local rings".
Nor does it make obvious the existence of a sheafification functor, as you have discovered for yourself.
Thus, we should focus on nice categories.
Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ has the following properties:

$\mathcal{C}$ has limits of small diagrams.

$\mathcal{C}$ has colimits of small filtered diagrams.

Filtered colimits in $\mathcal{C}$ preserve finite limits, i.e. for every small filtered category $\mathcal{J}$, the colimit functor $[\mathcal{J}, \mathcal{C}] \to \mathcal{C}$ preserves limits of finite diagrams.

Taking stalks detects sheaf isomorphisms, i.e. given a morphism $\alpha : F \to G$ of sheaves, if $\alpha_x : F_x \to G_x$ is an isomorphism for every $x \in X$, then $\alpha : F \to G$ is also an isomorphism.


These hypotheses are by no means minimal, but it makes the proof you propose work.
The last point is especially subtle: it is the deep magic that powers all proofs reducing propositions about sheaves (or morphisms thereof) to propositions about their stalks (or morphisms thereof), but I do not know how to paraphrase it as an intrinsic property of $\mathcal{C}$.
(To be clear, it is a non-trivial condition and can fail even for reasonably nice $\mathcal{C}$ and $X$.)
The above hypotheses are satisfied if $\mathcal{C}$ is a locally finitely presentable category, but in that case there is a cheat allowing us to reduce to the case $\mathcal{C} = \textbf{Set}$.
Changing notation slightly, for a presheaf $F$, let $\Lambda (F)$ be the $X$-indexed family where $\Lambda (F)_x$ is the stalk $F_x$; and for an $X$-indexed family $G$, let $\Pi (G)$ be the presheaf where $\Pi (G) (U) = \prod_{x \in U} G_x$.
It is easy to check that $\Pi (G)$ is always a sheaf.
There are evident natural morphisms $\eta_F : F \to \Pi (\Lambda (F))$ and $\epsilon_G : \Lambda (\Pi (G)) \to G$, and with a bit of work they are seen to be the unit and counit of an adjunction.
The induced comonad $\Pi \Lambda$ is precisely the one used to construct the Godement resolution: in the non-additive setting, that means we have an augmented simplicial object
$$F \overset{\eta_F}{\longrightarrow} \Pi (\Lambda (F)) \mathrel{\rlap{\longleftarrow}\vcenter{\longrightarrow \\ \longrightarrow}} \Pi (\Lambda (\Pi (\Lambda (F)))) \mathrel{\cdots}$$
such that applying $\Lambda$ to it is a split simplicial object; in particular, (by general abstract nonsense) we have the following (split) reflexive equaliser diagram:
$$\Lambda (F) \longrightarrow \Lambda (\Pi (\Lambda (F)) \mathrel{\rlap{\longleftarrow}\vcenter{\longrightarrow \\ \longrightarrow}} \Lambda (\Pi (\Lambda (\Pi (\Lambda (F)))))$$
The important (i.e. not abstract nonsense) point about the Godement resolution (and the reason why it is called so) is that the diagram before applying $\Lambda$ is an equaliser diagram if and only if $F$ is a sheaf.
(Not coincidentally, the morphisms $\Pi (\Lambda (F)) \rightrightarrows \Pi (\Lambda (\Pi (\Lambda (F))))$ are precisely the ones that appear in the lemma in the Stacks project you cite.)
So why is the Godement resolution indeed a resolution?
Since stalks are constructed by filtered colimits, the hypothesis on the compatibility of filtered limits and finite limits implies $\Lambda$ preserves finite limits.
The hypothesis about stalks and sheaf isomorphisms is precisely the statement that $\Lambda$ is conservative when restricted to the subcategory of sheaves.
Since the subcategory of sheaves is closed under limits, the equaliser of $\Pi (\Lambda (F)) \rightrightarrows \Pi (\Lambda (\Pi (\Lambda (F))))$ is a sheaf, say $\hat{F}$, and $\eta_F : F \to \Pi (\Lambda (F))$ factors through the equaliser $\hat{F} \to \Pi (\Lambda (F))$.
Consider the morphism $F \to \hat{F}$: since $\Lambda$ preserves finite limits, $\Lambda (F) \to \Lambda (\hat{F})$ is an isomorphism; thus, $F \to \hat{F}$ is an isomorphism if and only if $F$ is a sheaf.
Moreover, by naturality, if $G$ is a sheaf, then every morphism $F \to G$ factors uniquely through $F \to \hat{F}$.
Hence, $F \to \hat{F}$ exhibits $\hat{F}$ as the sheafification of $F$, so we have a sheafification functor as desired.

The above also proves that sheafification preserves finite limits, but if we only want a sheafification functor, examining the proof shows that we can weaken the hypothesis on filtered colimits: we only need the preservation of certain reflexive equalisers, just like in Beck's comonadicity theorem.
Curiously, although the definition of "sheaf" can be generalised to not require products, it is not possible to weaken the hypothesis on the existence of limits if we want sheafification for all presheaves and all topological spaces: sheafification over a discrete space $X$ is a machine for getting $X$-indexed products in $\mathcal{C}$, at least if $\mathcal{C}$ has an initial object.
There is an argument to be made that the hypothesis on stalks and sheaf isomorphisms should instead be the definition of "sheaf".
Formally, we would be localising the category of presheaves with respect to the morphisms that become isomorphisms after applying $\Lambda$.
There are two ways to interpret this: we can either insist on reflective localisation, which makes being a sheaf a mere property of a presheaf, or we can allow free localisation, which makes sheafification exist by fiat but at the cost of making sheaves so abstract that it is not obvious whether or not sheaves "are" presheaves.
(When we have a nice category as above, all these definitions agree.)
In any case, this line of thought is specific to topological spaces and toposes with enough points; it cannot be generalised to locales or general toposes without finding some replacement for the definition of local isomorphism.

Thank you for the great comprehensive answer! What is the cheat that works for locally finitely presentable categories, is there somewhere I can read about this?

Use the Yoneda embedding restricted to finitely presentable objects: for lfp $\mathcal{C}$, the representation $\mathcal{C} \to [\mathcal{C}_\textrm{fp}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ is fully faithful, preserves filtered colimits, and has a left adjoint.
